# NVD3 Update Chart with d3.json

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, nvd3.js

I've made a chart using NVD3, which populates 3 stacked bars.  On clicking a bar, I want an request to be fired, and for the chart to be populated with new data altogether.  Unfortunately, the chart does not REPLACE the data I previously had, but APPENDS a new bar to my chart, forming a chart with 4 stacked bars, when I only want 1 bar.  How can I remove the old data, while bringing in new data?

Thanks!

```
var chartData = setChartData(data1);

var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
  .barColor(d3.scale.category20().range())
  .margin({bottom: 100})
  ;

chart.multibar
  .hideable(true);

chart.reduceXTicks(false).staggerLabels(false);

chart.xAxis
    .axisLabel("Current Index")
    .showMaxMin(true)
    .tickFormat(function(d,i){ return allBillsForChart[d][0][2]});

chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

d3.select('#chart1 svg')
    .datum(chartData)
   .call(chart);

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e));   });

return chart;
},function(){
d3.selectAll(".nv-bar").on('click', function(d, i){                   
            d3.json("fakeURLToFetchData", function(error, data){
  arr = [];
  arr.push(data)
  handledData = setChartData(arr)

  d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(handledData).call(chart);
  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
  return chart
})
});
```

});

Comment: You would need to replace the existing data for that bar instead of appending it to the data you have. It looks like this would be handled by `setChartData`, the implementation of which you haven't shown us.

Comment: One potential issue I could see in here is that you call the window resize registration function (nv.utils.windowResize(...)) multiple times (and every time you do the onclick callback). This will result in the NVD3 chart being registered multiple times and will gradually slow down the window resize event as it will resize all the elements in the chart once for every time it's been registered with the resize event handler. As Lars mentions, you should provide a jsFiddle or Plnkr that demonstrates your problem and one of us can probably fix it.